# Connection string security in web.config

Tags: sql-server, security, iis

I have a web site due to go public which runs in IIS 7.5 under its own app pool. In the web.config for the site there is an un-encrypted connection string to a sql database.

Is it better to run the app pool under its own identity & then use sql authentication in the web.config to connect to the database, which would mean that I would lose the benefit of Kerbeos authentication to the db.

Or should I configure the app pool to run under its own identity & then use integrated security in the connection string to get the benefits of windows security ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the app pool and use integrated security if you have the option. #2 This has the benefit of not leaking your passwords if your site ever gets hacked. However, this won't prevent any SQL injection type attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that much control over the servers, then go with windows authentication.  While I can't say if it is "better", I would think it would be easier to manage.